# Query Sql Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table which contains theese fields:
Date - Amount - Section - PV
so I could have much record like this:

```
+ 01/01/22 - 1200,00 - 14 - 0
+ 02/02/22 - 900,00 - 14  - 0
+ 02/02/22 - 356,00 - 11  - 12
+ 02/02/22 - 432,00 - 14  - 0
```

At this moment, I use different query to get results from every group, i.e.

```
select SUM()...from ... where val(PV) = 0 or select SUM()... from ... where (PV) = 12
```

but i think that there is way to extract each value writing only one query faster than this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: First sentence 'This section describes aggregate functions that operate on sets of values. They are often used with a GROUP BY clause to group values into subsets.' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS Access?

Comment: I'm using ms access. In order to reply of @P.Salmon, i want to specify that the where clause prevents me to use grouping function.

Comment: 'where clause prevents me to use grouping function. ' - why and what is your desired outcome?

Comment: This is the real query: SELECT SUM(Amount) as cp FROM tblforn where " _
             & "Val(IndiceOP) = 14 AND val(Pv) = 0 and data " _
             & "<=  datevalue('31/12/22') I want to obtain the cp value in different conditions, i.e. when value of IndiceOp = 11 or value of PV = 0 and so on depending of combinations. Sorry if I was not clear

Comment: WHERE clause does not prevent use of grouping. Define 'group' for your data - Section or PV or both? Edit question to show desired output as well as the attempted SQL. Probably what you need are multiple Sum() calcs using IIf() or Switch() or Choose().

Comment: @P.Salmon your suggest helped me. I'm able to get values changing the select like this 'Select IndiceOp,Pv,sum(amount)  where... group by indiceop,pv...etc. As you have written I can save code and time. Thanks

Comment: It is so. In some query, unfortunately, I need multiple sum but I don't know use of switch or Choose. I will read something about it